# Скрипт удаления из файлов заданной информации

Tags: php, actionscript

Как изменить скрипт так, чтобы удалялась та информация, которую я задам.

```
<?
$RD = dirname(__FILE__);
function delVirus($dir)
{
    $m = glob($dir.'/*.js');
    $ml = sizeof($m);
    if($m)
        for($i = 0; $i < $ml; ++$i)
        {
            $t = file_get_contents($m[$i]);
            echo '['.$m[$i].']';
            if($s = strpos($t, "function OQWCY"))
            {
                $t = substr($t, 0, $s);
                $t = file_put_contents($m[$i], $t);
                echo ' +';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }

    if(!$handle = opendir($dir))
        break;
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file))
        {
            delVirus($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
}
delVirus($RD);
?>
```

Comment: >которую я задам

От строки до строки, от строки до конца, от позиции до позиции или как?

Comment: Нужно удалить только то что я пропишу 'тут' Точный текст от начала до конца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно удалить только то что я пропишу 'тут' Точный текст от начала до конца.

```
if($s = strpos($t, "function OQWCY"))
{
    $t = substr($t, 0, $s);
    $t = file_put_contents($m[$i], $t);
    echo ' +';
}
```

Замените на

```
$t = str_replace('_toDelete_', '', $t);
$t = file_put_contents($m[$i], $t);
echo ' +';
```

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы удалялся определенный вредоносный код. <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Пример:

    $t = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript">alert([33565.0.toString(36), 430.0.toString(36), 1003948.0.toString(36)].join(\' \'));</script>', '', $t);

Или используйте любые функции для изменения строк.